# How to configure final frame in Latex beamer?

Tags: latex, beamer

I am developing a beamer in Latex that has a titlepage, some frames and then the final frame. I am using the Darmstadt theme, so I have the table of contents on top of every slide of the beamer like this:

[image]

Each circle determines a frame, except from the titlepage and the table of contents frame, which do not have a circle (they are not like the regular frames). I want to put a final frame identical to the titlepage frame. However, it still has a circle and I do not know how to remove it. In the previous image, you can see that a final circle is left in the beamer. It corresponds to the final titlepage frame, but I want it to disappear.

Is there any way to make the circle disappear, to extract this final page from the table of contents on the top of the regular frames? Maybe there is a keyword for final frames that solves the problem.

Comment: Dear reviewers, this is a pure tex problem and unrelated to programming. I think it would be best if it would be migrated to tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: I did not know the existance of tex.stackexchange.com. I will migrate the question there. Thank you @samcarter.

Comment: @ Sergio Blanco My message was for the reviewers. I already flagged it for migration and they will decide if the question will be moved. You don't need to do anything

Comment: Ok, I understand, thank you @samcarter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In old beamer versions one could exclude frames from the headline navigation by placing them in a section with empty title (`\section{}`).

For up-to-date beamer versions, one can switch of the miniframe like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}

\makeatletter
\let\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson=\beamer@writeslidentry%
\def\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff{%
  \expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@framestartpage}{}% does not happen normally
  {%else
    % removed \addtocontents commands
    \clearpage\beamer@notesactions%
  }
}
\newcommand*{\miniframeson}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson}
\newcommand*{\miniframesoff}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{section name}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\miniframesoff

\begin{frame}
Thank you
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you have a thirst for adventure, you could use this experimental beamer branch

https://github.com/samcarter/beamer/tree/nominiframe

which has a `nominiframe` frame option which will suppress the miniframe for this frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{section name}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\section{}
\begin{frame}[nominiframe]
Thank you
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution, which is not very elegant, but still it works. You can put `\appendix` before the frames you do not want to appear in the table of contents. This can be used for a final frame or many more final frames.

```
...

\begin{frame}
example frame
\end{frame}

\appendix

\begin{frame}
final frame
\end{frame}

...
```